# SDL SetRenderDrawColor Opacity doesn't work

Tags: c, sdl

I have an issue with my code. I don't manage to change the opacity of my RenderDrawColor.

Indeed, I know that SetRenderDrawColor is defined by (renderer, R, G, B, a --> which represents the opacity value). Nevertheless, I tried to change a value but my color doesn't change and I have my rectangle fully fill again.

Here a photo of what I have with my code :

[Screen that I have with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52DCR.png)

Here is my code, that I execute with a main.c script :

```
void display_end_menu(SDL_Renderer *renderer) { 

if (SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 30) != 0) {
    return_error("Impossible de modifier la couleur du render"); 
    SDL_Quit(); 
}

SDL_Rect shadow_screen; 
shadow_screen.w = 1280; 
shadow_screen.h = 720; 
shadow_screen.x = (SCREEN_WIDTH - shadow_screen.w)/2; 
shadow_screen.y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - shadow_screen.h)/2;

if (SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &shadow_screen) != 0) {
    return_error("Impossible de dessiner le rectangle dans le render"); 
    SDL_Quit(); 
}

if (SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 30) != 0) {
    return_error("Impossible de modifier la couleur du render"); 
    SDL_Quit(); 
}
SDL_Rect quit_button; 
quit_button.w = 200; 
quit_button.h = 50; 
quit_button.x = (SCREEN_WIDTH - quit_button.w)/2; 
quit_button.y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - quit_button.h)/2;

if (SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &quit_button) != 0) {
    return_error("Impossible de dessiner le rectangle dans le render"); 
    SDL_Quit(); 
}
}
```

I tried several numbers for alpha such as 0, 30 and so on, but it's impossible to edit the opacity of the rectangle.

Comment: Try adding this guy: `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);`